# Set image source to picturebox which is added dynamically to Table Layout Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel, imagesource

I followed instructions from this page to insert controls to tableLayoutPanel.
http://goo.gl/SVKf8D

I am using this code to try to add a dynamic picturebox and set it's source:

```
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { Image.FromFile(TableLayoutPanelTool.Properties.Resources.BaldGuyImage)}, 0, 0);
```

I cannot insert image source  to picturebox this way.

What I need: A way to set the image to the Picturebox that I have added dynamically to the TableLayoutview

note:it is ok to give source directly.Something  like source= C:/Projects/bin/debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added the image into project's resources file, you can access them using Properties.Resources class. In this case, you can directly assign the resource into picturebox.image property:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { Image = TableLayoutPanelTool.Properties.Resources.BaldGuyImage}, 0, 0);
```

You could read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560105/change-pictureboxs-image-to-image-from-my-resources) and also from [here](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=dewmNEwiv4sC&pg=PA601&lpg=PA601&dq=assign%20resources%20to%20picture%20box%20image%20c%23&source=bl&ots=nNEpWJIatp&sig=R8Urfpm_7X_3fsxrGsmdCKwM2Wk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCGoVChMI3vfhyJKjxwIVg9qmCh2iowDw#v=onepage&q=assign%20resources%20to%20picture%20box%20image%20c%23&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I doenst work. It says "Cannot convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to string"

I just tried 
 tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { Image = BitConverter.ToString(Image.FromFile(TableLayoutPanelTool.Properties.Resources.BaldGuyImage)) }, 0, 0);

I doesn't work either.

It is also ok to give source directly as C:/Projects/bin/debug

Comment: Image.FromFile expectes a filename ie a string. You already have the Iamge in the resources so you can probably just use:  Image = (Image)(Table.....

Comment: @AhmedFaizan I have update the code. If you loaded the image from resources, just use Image = resource

Comment: Thanks.If you could provide the direct source method it would be cool as well.

Comment: @AhmedFaizan please see the edited post, I have added two links as reference