# Combining a string and resource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataset which contains some products and their image filenames (for example "test.png").
Images are loaded as resources. How can I set the image location properly?

```
DataRowView uRow = (DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = uRow.Row;

pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Properties.Resources + row["logo"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please tag with appropriate GUI technology: Webforms? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: I'm sorry, winforms it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a string resource by name like this:

```
string imageName = row["logo"].ToString();

// Strip off the extension, since it is not contained in the resource name.
imageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageName);

pictureBox1.ImageLocation =
    Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(imageName);
```

If you have stored the images themselves as resources, you can get them by name like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image =
    (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName);
```

Comment: It sounds like the Image itself is the resource, not the path, but this is still the right hint the OP needs.

Comment: Well, he puts the result into `ImageLocation`, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageLocation` property does not support using resources directly. From the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets the path or URL for the image to display in the
>   PictureBox.

To load an image that is a resource, please see [Change PictureBox's image to image from my resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560105/change-pictureboxs-image-to-image-from-my-resources)

Answer (score 0):

If you set property `Access modifier` of Resources.resx file to the `Friend` or `Public`
then images or another resources can be accessed without hardcoding names.
Visual Studio will generate a class and properties for every resources

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.YourImage;
```